# How, Where can i download original EASTL library?

Tags: stl, eastl

I already know GitHub thing.
But it isn't original EASTL.

I also heard about gpl.ea.com.

There are open source projects.

I heard the EASTL included in that project.

So I tried to find it in their projects but failed.

If you know a little bit about it,
tell me something, please.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK EASTL hasnt been published separated from the EAWebKit packages at http://gpl.ea.com/. So unless you want to repeat the work of Paul Hodge I suggest you use his fork at https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL

Comment: Thanks, Jano. the eastl is exist in the nfs world product. it could be found another product, but i don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only publicly available release (as of writing - Aug 1st 2011), is what's in the EA GPL webkit at the address you mention. Paul Hodge's github project ( https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL ), is simply just the EASTL code taken from the GPL webkit.

The latest info I could find about EASTL being released in it's full form, was here:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=60885

Paul Pedriana (the author of EASTL) mentions that the webkit/Hodge release is only 50-60% of the entire thing. He says he hopes to release the full library in that thread too, sometime in the future.

Comment: And it looks like EA has  released the EASTL themselves this month (Feb 2016): `git clone https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL.git`  (or visit the github page: https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL)